# ionic - Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3

Tags: android, gradle, ionic-framework

While trying to build ionic android, I got the following error from gradle.
Could you please help me with the problem?
BTW I have not installed Android Studio.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
    > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
    > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3.
    Required by:
    project :
    > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3.
    > Could not get resource
    'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle                             -2.2.3.pom'.
    > Could not GET
    'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle                             -2.2.3.pom'.
    > Permission denied: connect

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or
    --debug option to get more log output.

    BUILD FAILED

    Total time: 1 mins 27.452 secs
    Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
    > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
    > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3.
    Required by:
    project :
    > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3.
    > Could not get resource
    'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle                             -2.2.3.pom'.
    > Could not GET
    'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle                             -2.2.3.pom'.
    > Permission denied: connect

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or
    --debug option to get more log output.
```

Comment: Run command `gradlew -Dhttps.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8580` and use proxy

Comment: As Ahmad said you need to use VPN or proxy

Comment: Please [edit] the question since you've not *answered* the question

Comment: This also happens to me at my job. It could be related to a firewall problem. At home ionic runs just fine. It may be a closed port in your firewall.

Answer (score 0):

just use VPN for surfing free on web , for whole system use protocols like IPSEC L2P or blob